# write without absolute value symbols. |-7+√-49| So very lost help

Tags: complex-numbers

Working with imaginary number and so forth.It has to do with $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. I just can't seem to apply it correctly. I have the answer which is 7√2 but no idea why and I have no idea what steps to take to get there. I have looked at my book over and over and I do not really see anything similar enough to help me but what I have mentioned

Comment: HINT:  $$\sqrt{-49}=\pm i7$$

Comment: using the hint, do you still have problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note, $|a+bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.  Hence we have
$$ \left|-7 + \sqrt{-49}\right| = |-7 + 7i| = \sqrt{(-7)^2 + 7^2} =\sqrt{2\cdot 49} = 7\sqrt{2}. $$

---

To be pedantic:  $\sqrt{-49}$ is not uniquely defined to be $7i$.  Properly understood, the square root function is defined on a Riemann surface that is a two-fold cover of the complex plane.  To properly interpret $\sqrt{-49}$, it is necessary to specify which part of that cover we are living on, i.e. to specify a branch of the square root function.  However, the only possible choices give
$$ \sqrt{-49} = 7i
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\sqrt{-49} = -7i.
$$
However, we typically interpret $\sqrt{a}$ to mean the principal square root, which (in this case) is $7i$.  In either case, we obtain
$$
|-7 + \sqrt{-49}|
= \sqrt{(-7)^2 + (\pm 7)^2}
= 7\sqrt{2}.
$$

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks a bunch. makes total sense now!

Comment: $$\sqrt{-49} = \pm 7i$$

Comment: @AhmedS  Wasn't my downvote, but as I mention, the answer cuts corners.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what all the voting stuff is. The downvote was my mistake. Sorry I am totally new at any of this and I have no idea what its all about yet. I don't know how to fix it. I have never heard of this medium on the web and am not familiar.

Comment: @amWhy I recognize that the answer cuts corners---I nearly added a bit about choosing a branch of $\sqrt{\cdot}$, but my goal was to tailor the answer to the question, which was clearly not at that level.

Comment: @mmm_coffee  Again: ignorance is not an excuse.

Comment: kudos for your edit @XanderHenderson.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $(7i)^2=?$ How does this let us rewrite $-7+\sqrt{-49}$? Can you you take it from there?

Comment: Yessum! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You're very welcome. By the way, welcome to Math.SE! Something to keep in mind is that you can only accept ("check") one answer to each of your questions. After you get some more reputation (I think 10 is all you need), you'll be able to upvote any number of answers to your questions.

Comment: I have no clue about anything of what the rules are yet. hahaha.. I didn't realize what an upcheck was or any of the other stuff. I guess I'm a newbie to this type of websites. Something blinked a "you made an error" thing and I"m sure its what ever it is your talking about. hahaha

Comment: @mmm_coffee  hahaha? please do not ask another question until you've taken the site tour, and spent a modicum of time reviewing FAQ about the site.

Comment: @mmm_coffee: At the top of your page, you'll see a "help" button. I strongly suggest that you click it, then take the tour of this site. I take it that I'm not the first to have suggested this to you, but I hope to be the last.